# How can I retrieve the input/output token mint addresses of a Jupiter swap transaction?

Tags: web3.js, transactions, swap, jupiter, address

I am monitoring swap transactions on Jupiter, but I am encountering an issue because Jupiter uses different routes for transactions each time, resulting in data appearing in different indices. Is there a way to create a generic implementation to obtain input/output addresses?

For example, if I fetch a transaction with a signature like this:

```
const tx = await connectionMainnet.getParsedTransaction('2v36qHKKirrp6nsP2R92SN16NDc1dtZYNtnyXAKQZNBWrQeWsRxZkAMbQcodeLfbafRjye2J3JM32VS9aEQyJeVr', {maxSupportedTransactionVersion:0 });
```

I am looking for a generic function that takes a transaction and returns the input/output mint addresses of the token.

Input token: Sol - So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112

Output token: USDC - EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to look at the pre and post token balances in the transaction in `preTokenBalances` and `postTokenBalances`: https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransaction

So you want to see which user account has lost tokens (input) and which user account has gained tokens (output). You might end up getting it wrong, because the protocol inside of Jupiter is receiving the input tokens, and sending the output token.

To identify the "user" accounts, you could see if they are owned by the fee payer on the transaction.